# How to convert and read Khmer PDFs on Kindle?

Tags: kindle, calibre, ebook-readers, kindle-paperwhite, language

I was able to find a PDF in Khmer language(a.k.a. Cambodian language). However, when I tried to upload it into my kindle, it turns everything into gibberish. I've looked around and there aren't many resources when it comes to uploading Khmer books into kindle.

I tried using Calibre and also to transfer the book by pasting it directly into the Kindle's download folder, but it sorts of translate everything into English gibberish. I believe I need to manually add the language in first, but I'm not sure how.

Some said the kindle will know what to download when you upload a foreign language book, but it's not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the text into a PDF viewer that lets you print the PDF *as a PDF image*, e.g. the free [PDF-XChange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer).

[image: Print PDF as Image]

Alternatively, install the needed Khmer fonts on the Kindle. If you open the PDF in a text editor, you should see, *somewhere* in the docuiment, any special fonts it uses.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a Kindle, so I cannot test any solution. On saving PDF's, there is an option to include all font into the document (bigger file), only the used characters, or none of it (smallest file, relies on the system to provide the fonts).

I expect that if you edit the PDF and save it with the font definition included, it will work - provided Kindle can read and use fonts from inside the PDF.

With this solution, the file remains searchable - unlike saving the file as a series of pictures.